# Enigmatic & Intriguing French Artwork

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, visual

Last evening, in France, at a friend's art exhibition, I came across this intriguing and enigmatic artwork which had a few square shaped boxes.

My friend asked - *"So, what do you think? How many squares do you see?"*

I counted, and recounted just to make sure I am not counting it wrong. With a grin on my face, I replied *"Ah! Easy...There are 17 squares."*

My friend laughingly said - *"Non! Look carefully, can you see the 18th square?"*

I was left confused and baffled. I rechecked but no luck. Finally, I gave up and asked for a hint.

My friend handed me a note which said -

> *Hidden behind the shadows is a mystery you need to see.*
> *Moving five boxes is the only key.*

***Can you help me find the hidden 18th square?***
[image]

Comment: Are the shadows important?

Comment: @1357924680a Very important. :)

Comment: Well, important. I am doing a key.

Comment: are the directions of the shadows important?

Comment: @RonnieChen If you are asking where they are facing is important, then yes.

Comment: Hm. So we have to move five boxes. There are five letters corresponding to [pieces here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)). But what is the significance of the setting in France? There are also five pièces [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_alg%C3%A9brique), but I wonder whether it is something to do with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY), which might explain the "key". I'm still in the shadows.

Comment: @MOehm I can confirm, France is only used for fitting the storyline.. And well, let me confirm, its neither of those two links. :) I ll just add a new tag to it. The solution is pretty straighforward. And literally moving 5 *boxes* is all you need ;)

Comment: Neither of those three links. Missed the third link.

Comment: @MOehm I suspect its [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display_character_representations)

Comment: I see. Now to find out what _boxes_ means. Billyb's suggestion is another puzzling evergreen, but I don't really see how to apply it here.

Comment: Wordplay? Oh, I cant be waiting for punz.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Merci, for this brain teaser! After hitting *many* rabbit holes it struck me. Reminds me of my days of studying arts at Rennes studying artists using lights and shadows for their artwork... Reminds me of [Trompe-l'œil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-l%27%C5%93il). Here is the 18th Square...

> [image]
>  i.e. 324 displayed on 7-segment display
>  [image]

The artwork summary...

> You are asked to find the 18th square by moving 5 boxes..Shadows are important...Hmm...Good. I was able to find 5 boxes i.e. squares which spell out *boxes* going from left to right and top to bottom....
>  [image]
>
>  I tried to fit in all the possible places to see if I can build something but it went in vain until I started to see numbers being formed...specifically here it looks like a 7 segment display of number 3...
>  [image]
>
>  Aha, and the rest was a cake walk then....
>  18th square is $18^2 = 324$
>
>  [image]

Comment: Great Job! Wonderful explanations :)

Answer (score 3):

## This is not an answer.

Here is a key to the 17 squares on the picture of the puzzle, with the direction of the shadows pointing to with the squares. Semicolons represent new lines.

```
B-UP NULL NULL I-NONE NULL O-LEFT NULL; NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL M-NONE NULL; NULL NULL NULL K-UP NULL NULL NULL NULL; NULL T-RIGHT NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL R-RIGHT; F-DOWN Y-RIGHT NULL G-DOWNRIGHT NULL NULL U-DOWN W-RIGHT; NULL P-NONE NULL NULL X-RIGHT NULL NULL NULL; NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL; E-DOWN NULL NULL S-DOWN NULL NULL R-NONE NULL
```

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is to the solvers but definitely helpful for me to know that there's nothing wrong with the visuals. +1 for the efforts :)

Comment: Shouldn't that be «Ceci n'est pas une réponse»? `:)` (I know, I know, [he](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Magritte) was Belgian, not French.)

Comment: @MOehm Exactly lol